# AssociationType Mismatch in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, associations

I have a model, HighSchool (high_school.rb), that is extends User, and a model Athlete, (athlete.rb), that also extends User. In Athlete, it has a belongs_to :high_school. In HighSchool, it has a has_many :athletes.

When trying to create the Athlete from the HighSchool controller, which worked fine before I added the belongs_to and has_many (because I didn't have a high_school_id column in Athlete at that time), it breaks. The following is the error I receive, any ideas what the problem is?

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (HighSchool(#2194641240) expected, got 
String(#2151984260)):
app/controllers/high_school_controller.rb:6:in `new'
app/controllers/high_school_controller.rb:6:in `create_high_school_athlete'
config/initializers/disable_assets_logger.rb:10:in `call'
```

Here is the HighSchoolController:

```
class HighSchoolController < ApplicationController

def create_high_school_athlete
  athlete_attributes = params[:athlete]
  athlete_attributes = construct_athlete_attributes(athlete_attributes)
  @high_school_athlete = Athlete.new(athlete_attributes)

  if @high_school_athlete.valid? && @high_school_athlete.save
    stat_success = create_athlete_stats(@high_school_athlete, params)
        if stat_success[:success]
            respond_to do |format|
                format.json { render json: { errors: @high_school_athlete.errors.full_messages } }
            end
        else
            @high_school_athlete.destroy
            respond_to do |format|
                format.json { render json: { errors: stat_success[:error_messages] } }
            end
        end
  else
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: { errors: @high_school_athlete.errors.full_messages } }
        end
  end
end

def create_athlete_stats high_school_athlete, params
  @height = high_school_athlete.stat(:height)
  @weight = high_school_athlete.stat(:weight)

  height_in_inches = (params[:height_feet][:value].nil? ? 0 : params[:height_feet][:value].to_f * 12) + (params[:height_inches][:value].nil? ? 0 : params[:height_inches][:value].to_f)

  @height.value = height_in_inches.to_s
  @weight.value = params[:weight][:value]

  if @height.save && @weight.save
    {:success => true, :error_messages => ""}
  else
    {:success => false, :error_messages => @height.errors.full_messages + @weight.errors.full_messages}
  end
end

private

def construct_athlete_attributes athlete_attributes
  athlete_attributes[:username] = create_athlete_username(params[:athlete][:first_name], params[:athlete][:last_name])
  athlete_attributes[:password] = (36**(16-1) + rand(36**16)).to_s(36)
  athlete_attributes[:password_confirmation] = athlete_attributes[:password]
  athlete_attributes[:user_type_id] = 1
  athlete_attributes[:account_type_id] = 1
  athlete_attributes[:state] = current_high_school.state
  athlete_attributes[:hometown] = current_high_school.hometown
  athlete_attributes[:high_school] = current_high_school.high_school
  athlete_attributes[:high_school_id] = current_high_school.id

  athlete_attributes
end
```

It's a pretty long ajax call, but the parameters directly from the Ajax call (according to Rails' log) is the following:

```
Started POST "/high_school/create_high_school_athlete" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-10 10:45:29 -0500
Processing by HighSchoolController#create_high_school_athlete as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DIzC7Ix45dbXklLvYjbGf9i1sn67amaJYvG6zs5fhUA=", 
    "athlete"=>{"first_name"=>"a", "last_name"=>"a", "recruit_year"=>"2015", 
    "primary_sport_id"=>"6", "primary_sport_primary_position_id"=>"", 
    "secondary_sport_id"=>"", "email"=>"TEST@blah.com", "birthday"=>""}, "height_feet"=>
    {"value"=>"5"}, "height_inches"=>{"value"=>"9"}, "weight"=>{"value"=>"160"}}
```

Lastly, printing the athlete_attributes (just before Athlete.new is called with it as the parameter) using debugger shows this:

```
(rdb:1) p athlete_attributes
{"first_name"=>"a", "last_name"=>"a", "recruit_year"=>"2015", "primary_sport_id"=>"6", 
"primary_sport_primary_position_id"=>"", "secondary_sport_id"=>"", 
"email"=>"TEST@blah.com", "birthday"=>"", "username"=>"aa", 
"password"=>"c5n9abih4q705yet", "password_confirmation"=>"c5n9abih4q705yet", 
"user_type_id"=>1, "account_type_id"=>1, "state"=>"AL", "hometown"=>"blahtown", 
"high_school"=>"Blah University", "high_school_id"=>109}
```

Comment: can you post your models and the controller action?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are passing the `high_school` attribute, but you should ONLY pass the `high_school_id` attribute. Not really sure dough, lots of code going on here. Your user should only have the id, and the name of the high school he should get from the high school table

Comment: high_school is a separate field unrelated to this, which may be where my issue is coming from.